# A permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\dots,14\}$ has $2$ cycles of length $4$ and $2$ cycles of length $3$. How many $\pi$ are there s.t. $\pi^2=\sigma$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-cycles

> A permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\dots,14\}$ has $2$ cycles of length $4$ and $2$ cycles of length $3$. How many permutations $\pi$ are there st $\pi^2=\sigma$?

So $\pi$ could be made of $1$ cycle of length $8$ and $2$ cycles of length $3$ or $1$ cycle of length $8$ and $1$ cycle of length $6$.
For the first option there are $4$ such permutation and for the second there are $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ permutations. But now we need to count how many ways we can distribute the $14$ elements for each of the two above options.

For the first case there are $\frac{14!}{8 \cdot 3 \cdot 3!}$ permutations and for the second one there are $\frac{14!}{48}$ permutations.

So in total we have
$$
4 \cdot \frac{14!}{8 \cdot 3 \cdot 3!} + 12 \cdot \frac{14!}{48}.
$$
But this is on the order of $10^{10}$, which is very suspicious. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you perhaps counting how many permutations "square to" a permutation that is *isomorphic to* $\sigma$? It might be better to fix $\sigma = (1\,2\,3\,4)(5\,6\,7\,8)(9\,10\,11)(12\,13\,14)$ without loss of generality.

Comment: @BrianTung For a fixed $\sigma$ there are 16 permutations $\pi$. But shouldn´t we count how many permutations $\sigma$ there are and then multiply by 16? Which gave me $\frac{14!}{144}$. So the final result should be $16.\frac{14!}{144}$?

Comment: That's not the way I would read that question. To me, the first sentence fixes $\sigma$ to be an arbitrary but single permutation of the form described. We then are asked to find the number of permutations that "square to" that specific $\sigma$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first look at the $8$-cycle.  An element of the first $4$-cycle can permute to any of the $4$ elements of the other $4$-cycle, *and nowhere else*.  That "target" then must permute to the second element of the first $4$-cycle, which in turn must go to the second element of the second $4$-cycle.  In short, there are $4$ possible $8$-cycles that work because your choice of the first "target" completely determines the $8$-cycle.  (Thanks to @Daniel Schleper for the catch here.)

Similarly, if you have a $6$-cycle, there are $3$ possible $6$-cycles that work.  There also is exactly $1$ pair of $3$-cycles that work.  Therefore, there are $4 \cdot(3+1)=16$ permutations $\pi$ such that $\pi^2 = \sigma$.

Comment: For a fixes $\sigma$ there are 16 permutations $\pi$. But shouldn´t we count how many permutations $\sigma$ there are and then multiply by 16? Which gave me $\frac{14!}{144}$. So the final result should be $16.\frac{14!}{144}$?

Comment: I agree with @BrianTung that the question fixes a specific $\sigma$.